# What does it mean for the $(S^{-1}R)$-module $S^{-1}M$ to be compatible with the $R$-module structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, definition, localization

From *Algebra, Chapter $0$* by Aluffi:

> [image]

I think $S^{-1}M$ will be an $S^{-1}R$-module naturally since $M$ is an $R$-module: we define the action of $a/s_0 \in S^{-1}R$ on $m/s \in S^{-1}M$ by
$$\frac{a}{s_0} \cdot \frac{m}{s} := \frac{a\cdot m}{s_0s}.$$

**What does it mean for the $(S^{-1}R)$-module $S^{-1}M$ to be compatible with the $R$-module structure?**

Comment: I guess it means that, denoting by $r/s$ and $m/s$ the equivalence classes of $(r,s)$ and $(m,s)$, it holds $(r/1)(m/1)=(rm)/1$.

Comment: it means the natural group hom $M\rightarrow S^{-1}M, m\mapsto m/1$ is an R module hom

Answer (score 1):

Say you have two rings $R, T$ and a morphism $i:R\to T$ and an $R$-module $M$, a $T$-module $N$, and an abelian group morphism $f:M\to N$.

Then $f$ is "compatible" with all this data if when we give $N$ the induced $R$-module structure ($r\cdot n := i(r)n$) $f$ is an $R$-module morphism.

Here, $i:R\to S^{-1}R$ is the canonical map and $f:M\to S^{-1}M$ is also the canonical map.

Concretely, it boils down to $(r/1)(m/1) = (rm)/1$ for all $r\in R, m\in M$

Comment: Can we also say: Since $M$ is an $R$-module, we have $R \times M \to M$ and since $S^{-1}M$ is an $S^{-1}R$-module we have $S^{-1}R \times S^{-1}M \to S^{-1}M$. So, $S^{-1}M$ is compatible with the $R$-module structure on $M$ if $S^{-1}R \times S^{-1}M \to S^{-1}M$ when restricted to $(r,m)$ is equal to $R \times M \to M$?

Comment: In a sense yes, although the word "restricted" is a bit misleading because $R \to S^{-1}R$ is not necessarily injective

Comment: Why isn't $R \to S^{-1}R$ necessarily injective? Don't we always just have $r \mapsto r/1$?

Comment: This osn't always injective : if $s\in S$ and $sx=0$ then $x=0$ in $S^{-1}R$

Comment: Ok I see. Also, can we say that $M$ is an $S^{-1}R$-module? It seems like we let $\frac{r}{s} \cdot m =\frac{rm}{s}$. Or no? It seems this follows from $S^{-1}M$ being an $S^{-1}R$-module by looking at $\frac{m}{1}=m$.

Comment: No, $s$ might not be invertible in $M$ so this idn't well-defined